# When the Kloosterman sum is an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, finite-fields, exponential-sums

Let $q$ be a power of prime $p$ and $\zeta_p$ be the complex $p$ th root
 of unity. We denote by
$\mathbb{F}_q$ the finite field of $q$ elements and by $Tr$ the absolute trace function $\mathbb{F}_q\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ . The **Kloosterman sum** at a point $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$ is defined by the equation

$\hspace{3cm} K_{q}(a)=\displaystyle\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q^*}\psi(x+ax^{-1})$

where $\psi:\mathbb{F}_q\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is the canonical additive character of $\mathbb{F}_q$ defined by $\psi(x)=\zeta_p^{Tr(x)}.$

**FACT.** It is known that $K_{q}(a)\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $p=2,3$.

> **QUESTION.** Does there exist a prime $p\; (\ne 2,3$) such that $K_{q}(a)\in \mathbb{Z} ?$

Comment: B Fisher has studied the Galois action on Kloosterman sums in "Distinctness of Kloosterman sums"  (Contemp. Math., vol.
133, pp. 81-102) and "Kloosterman sums as algebraic integers" (Math. Ann. 301, 485--505, 1995).  These papers might have the answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you @DenisChaperondeLauzières. I have gone through those papers, as for my knowledge Fisher hasn't discussed  the above  problem. But those papers gave me some useful information. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Kononen, Rinta-Aho, and Vaananen, On integer values of Kloosterman sums, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 56 (August 2010) 4011-4013, MR2752481 (2011m:11167), discuss the question, and give some examples with $q=25$; if $\alpha$ is a primitive element, then $\alpha^3,\alpha^9,\alpha^{15},\alpha^{21}$ are all said to work.

Comment: @sam, note that there's no need to @ the poster; he or she will automatically be notified.